# install apk on sdcard

Tags: android

> adb install [-l] [-r] [-s]  - push this package file to the device and install it
>
> ```
>                    ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
>
>                    ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data)
>
>                    ('-s' means install on SD card instead of internal storage)
> ```

how to use  the last option that is install apk on sdcard

Comment: Third time the user asked the ecxact same question [how to install apk on sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099230/how-to-install-apk-on-sdcard) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099114/how-to-install-apk-on-sdcard)

Comment: sorry but i am not getting exact answer..

Comment: reposting will just annoy us and you wont get a better answer just downvotes and people turning away from your questions... try to add comments to the answers on your questions if you don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use this command if you have a device running froyo (Android 2.2) if you are using the 1.6 G1 you are mentioning in your other posts installing the app on the sd card is not possible.

Comment: thanks friend.....means on android g1 with sdk 1.5 it is not possible to install apk on sdcard....is it like that..

Comment: abhishekh, you should be aware that install on sd card is supported only 2.2 and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
As mentioned by Januz, The option to move or install an application on SD card is only present (and hopefully will continue) in the Android 2.2 OS currently. So for installing the apk from sd-card the only other option you have is to download the apk installation app from Android Market (its free as far as i know) named "App Installer" and use it to install the package onto your device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: exactly... sorry for a bit misguided answer... but though u can install app "FROM" sd card, U cant install app "IN" sd card memory. The only exception as of now is the (Froyo)Android 2.2 where both the above can be done!! (sorry 4 the late reply :) )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll allow you to pick and choose which applications it'll let you install to your sdcard but apps2sd will let you move all of your apps to the card.

There are however some caveats:

You need a rooted phone

You may need a recovery Rom installed (I'm not sure).

Your best bet is to install a custom rom which comes with apps2sd built in such as VillainROM or Cyanogen.

Then you'll need to partition your sdcard to include an ext2 partition which won't be visible and follow whatever other instructions are necessary to complete the transfer.

You won't be able to unmount the card whilst the phone is on, if the card is less than a Class 4 device you'll also have various other problems.

HTH even if it's not exactly what you wanted.